# Selenium Firefox webdriver issues

Tags: python, linux, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox

Below is the python code that I am trying to run

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

binary = '/usr/bin/firefox'
options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.binary = binary
options.add_argument('start-maximized')
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.headless=False
options.binary_location = '/usr/bin/firefox'
driverService = Service('/usr/bin/geckodriver')
options.add_argument('window-size=1920x1080')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
cap = DesiredCapabilities().FIREFOX
cap["marionette"] = True

driver = Firefox(capabilities=cap, options=options, service=driverService)
driver.capabilities['browserVersion']
print(driver.capabilities['browserVersion'])
```

I don't know what version of firefox I'm using and I don't know how to find that out, selenium is 4.1.5 and geckodriver is 0.31
On running this, I get

```
  driver = Firefox(capabilities=cap, options=options, service=driverService)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xtesting/ci/./ui_testing_firefox.py", line 30, in <module>
    driver = Firefox(capabilities=cap, options=options, service=driverService)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 180, in __init__
    RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 275, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 365, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 430, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Process unexpectedly closed with status signal
```

I am unable to find a specific solution to resolve this issue, I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: you need to check webdriver logs

Comment: This is what I got in the logs ```*** You are running in headless mode.
JavaScript error: chrome://remote/content/RemoteAgent.jsm, line 36: NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE: Disabled by preference
firefox: unable to start remote agent: unavailable
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
Exiting due to channel error.
1653374581188   geckodriver     INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:41782
1653374581206   mozrunner::runner       INFO    Running command: "/usr/bin/firefox" "--marionette" "--headless" "window-size=1```

Comment: @SamarthGoyal did you ever fix this issue? I am experiencing the same thing